# How can I make the sentiment analysis plot look nicer?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, r-markdown, sentiment-analysis

I am currently finishing up an assignment in my R programming class. I needed to plot the sentiment value vs the location in the book, the book in question was Jane Austen's "Pride and Prejudice." I got everything plotted correctly, I just need to make it look nicer as it looks "clustered" and rather clunky.

This is what I have so far:
[image]

I need to use a smoother of some sort, as per the assignment, and I would like to get this plot to look a little better instead of this clustered mess. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: One cool thing that will really show the distribution is adding `alpha =  .1` to your points ex: `geom_point(alpha = .2)`. The data is what it is, you can't force it. you can make another plot as `qeom_line()` to use smooth, as it's a function to model your data, hence it's a line plot

Comment: @DanielJachetta, thanks for the info and the edit! I also realized that I was using the incorrect arguments for my x and y values. I will answer this question with my corrected code in a few moments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 library(ggplot2)
 words_2 %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = word_num, y = value)) +
 geom_point(alpha = 0.2, show.legend = F) +
 geom_smooth() + 
 labs(x = "Location in the book (in ascending order)", 
   y = "Sentiment score")
```

After using this code, this is the plot that is generated:
[image: sentiment score plot]

Initially, I used the incorrect variables to plot. I fixed them and used some arguments to make it a little sharper. The next problem in the book was specifically asking to make the plot look more readable using the `group_by` function.